# Display Object list from server in a Select option in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I receive a list of Grades that are in the right format ( $key => $value) in a $grades variable

How can I fill a select option input with Vue using this variable.

I guess I must bind the vue variable with : but I'm just beginning with vue and I can find so very little basic examples,

```
<select v-model="grades" class="form-control">
       <option v-for="gradeValue in gradeValues" :gradeValues="{{ $grades /* Laravel Variable */ }}">@{{ gradeValue }}</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: I could make an ajax call from Vue, this should not be so complicated, but as the page load, my Laravel controller passes variables to my View, so, this is for me a cleaner aproach, in this case there is no need for ajax.

Comment: you should set the variables that come from the server in a vue hook like `ready` or `created`

Comment: thing is I can't use laravel variables outside of blade files (.blade.php). that's my problem. So, my problem is how to asign a variable inside the html, and then get the variable in vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

You can create the `option` elements using blade's `foreach` method:

```
@foreach ($grades as $grade)
    <option ...>{{ $grade }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Or** you can create a dedicated component for your `grades` with your template and pass in the `$grades` variable. For example:

```
<grades :grades="{{ $grades }}"></grades>
```

Comment: I tested the first solution , and it works for the front end, but will I be able to access grades in js? Also, I could make a component, but it is worth if it is only a dropdown in the page? Also, how should I select default value??? Tx for your help @Alexandros

Comment: I suggest you to create a component with a property `grades`. This way you will have access to the data in js. 

To set a default value you can conditionally apply `selected` attribute. For example `<option ... selected="yourExpresssion">`

Comment: ok, but, so, I have 3 combos, 2 input text, 1 one label field in my page. The goal of this is setting the label fields according to the selected options. So I should have 3 components + 1 global component for this page? Is it ok? Or what should use best use vue in this case?

Comment: You dont need so many things. You can can simple create the option whichever way you prefer and the bind the `select` element to a variable using `v-model`. For example:

`<select v-model="selected">...</select>`

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/hootlex/489cezpm/

Comment: You answered my first question, so I will accept your answer. Now, I will ask another question and link to this question, because it is not clear for me how should I proceed with Vue

Comment: next question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698847/what-is-the-way-to-do-it-with-vuejs

Answer (score 2):

I think this has been over complicated for you, your code in this question looks close.  Is your Vue component in the same file as your blade? Then it's just:

html

```
<select v-model="selectedGrade" class="form-control">
   <option v-for="(grade, val) in grades" :value="val">@{{ grade }}</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
new Vue({
  ...
  data:function(){
    return { 
      grades:{{ $grades }},
      selectedGrade:2 //some default value
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

If your component is in a separate file you still don't need a separate component for each select dropdown, you just need to pass all the required info into one component. Without a better understanding of your app, I'd guess it could be something like this:

```
<person-data :grades="{{ $grades }}" :categories="{{ $categories }}" :ages="{{ $ages }}"></person-data>
```

then the vue component:

```
var PersonData = Vue.extend({
  props:['grades','categories','ages']
});
```

Comment: and then how should I set default with the second option? I tried to put it in the same file but I get: "require is not defined"

Comment: You can add: Vue.component('person-data', PersonData); to your answer, component needs to be registered

Comment: It's working, but I don't know how to reach js var. When I try: console.log(PersonData); it shows Vue Component, When I open it in Vue DevTool, I can see content, but when I try to access (PersonData.grades) or PersonData['grades'] I get undefined

Comment: Within the component you just refer to `this.grades`

Comment: I am very confused ( and kind of upset with Vue ). I made a JSBin. http://jsbin.com/womevex/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Here is an updated, working jsbin.  Vue has a famously simple API so I hope this helps you understand how it works in your app: http://jsbin.com/tiyuxinihi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: The reason you need to use a component even though you aren't recreating this portion is because you have the component defined outside the `.blade` file.  You either need to retrieve the data with ajax or pass it into a component, like this.