# What is the way to do it with Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a page with 3 combos, 6 dependents inputs text ( if a special value is selected in combo, it will show, otherwise it will hide)

Then, I will have A text fields that is a computed property. Each time an input is changed, it will reevaluate this field value.

So, For instance, My fields are:

- GradeIni, GradeFin, Category, AgeCategory, AgeIni, AgeFin , Gender (selects)
- isTeam ( Checkbox )
- CategoryFullName

So, for example, There is 5 predefines AgeCategory,and the 6th is Custom, when Selected, it show AgeIni and AgeFin

Each time a value is change, CategoryFullName is reevaluated.

[My first answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658336/display-object-list-from-server-in-a-select-option-in-vue/36669236?noredirect=1#comment60978474_36669236) was how to get values from server.

I knew how to do it with Ajax, but in this case, it was easier to just use Server variable sent by Laravel when pages load.

So, the answer was 2 options:

```
@foreach ($grades as $grade)
    <option ...>{{ $grade }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Or

```
<grades :grades="{{ $grades }}"></grades>
```

So, I would like to use the second one, but it means I have to create a component for each Select Option in my page, which seems a little heavy.

So, I'm a little bit confused about how should I make this page. Is it better by AJAX, is it better to be able to get data from laravel, and o make a component for each list, or is there a better way to do it????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use many components. One component and one variable to keep the selected grade are fine.

You can create a component template to display all the grades.
I have created one template with dummy data to show you how you can do it.

```
<template id="grades-list">
    Curently selected: Title {{selected.title}} Value: {{selected.value}}
    <select v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="grade in grades" :value="grade">{{grade.title}}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

The component should be registered like this:

```
Vue.component('grades', {
    props: ['grades', 'selected'],
    template: '#grades-list'
})
```

The tricky part is how you will select a default value and keep it synced with the parent. To do so, you can use `.sync`

```
<!-- you can use :grades="{{ grades }}" with Blade too-->
<grades :grades="grades" :selected.sync="selectedGrade"></grades>
```

To set default value you can update the `selectedGrade` variable when the document is ready, using [`vm.$set`](http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-set).

```
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
        'selectedGrade': ''
    },
    ready() {
        this.$set('selectedGrade', this.grades[1])
    }
})
```

I have created an example with dummy data [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hootlex/Lajv4ooj/1/).

Comment: this works well for 1 component x select, but if I have 3 select, I will have 3 components?

Comment: You can include the component 3 times. you can add for example `<grades :grades="gradesFin" :selected.sync="selectedGrade"></grades>` above of your grades

Comment: what about age, category, etc?